# Java Spring Security : is it good practice to separate the user data from the userdetails?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

First of all, this is what I mean by good practice :

- code that is easy to maintain / fix
- code that can be scaled
- an architecture that is not going to cause security issues

With this out of the way, here is my problem :

I have a User class, currently it extends the UserDetails and has additional data attached to it not relevant to security ( for example purposes, let's say I added a user description / a profile page and data ). It works well and I can log in using it.

I, however, have seen tutorials and colleagues separate the data from the user details. They have a MyUserDetails class that only does the bare bones and encapsulates a User class that is used as a data container and nothing more.

[Here](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-boot-security-role-based-authorization-tutorial) is a good example of what I mean ( user related classes are roughly
in the middle )

Currently my implementation "works" but I am unsure if it's good practice and am unsure if I should separate the elements contained in my own user class as I don't know if it's any better.

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If by UserDetails you mean org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails class - then it's definitely good idea to separate it from your application model. [Single responsibility](https://www.baeldung.com/java-single-responsibility-principle) - one of key stones of good software architecture.